# How do I make this loop for a Nim Game?

Tags: java

Basically, I'm making a Nim game and the code stops looping after the first 2 sequences of the game. The first being the player taking stones out and then the computer taking stones out. I'm trying to make it so it keeps repeating the loop until the stones hit 0. Where would I need to change my while statement in order to fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Nim {

    public static int validEntry2(int comp) {
        int cm = 1;
        int newStones = 1;
        while (cm == 1) {
            comp = drawStones(comp);
            if ( comp < 1 || comp > 3 || comp < newStones) {
                System.out.println("Invalid parameters. Please enter something between 1-3.");
            } else
                System.out.println("Computer picks " + comp + " stones");
                cm = 2;
        }
        return comp;
    }

    public static int validEntry(int player) {
        int pl = 1;
        int newStones = 1;
        while (pl == 1) {
            player = playerStones(player);
            if (player < 1 || player > 3 || player < newStones) {
                System.out.println("Invalid parameters. Please enter something between 1-3.");
            } else
                pl = 2;
        }
        return player;
    }

    public static int drawStones(int comp) {
        comp = (int)(3 * Math.random() + 1);
        return comp;
    }

    public static int playerStones(int player) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many stones do you want to take?");
        player = input.nextInt();
        return player;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int stones;
        stones = (int)(16 * Math.random() + 15);
        int newStones = stones;
        int player = 1;
        int comp = 1;
        int pl = 1;
        // Display how many stones there are.
        System.out.println("There are currently " + stones + " stones left");
        //Players turn
        while (pl == 1) {
            player = validEntry(player);
            if ( (newStones - player) < 0 ) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            } else {
                pl = 2;
                newStones -= player;
            }
                // Does the player lose?
            if (newStones == 0) {
                System.out.println("You just lost to a computer.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("There are " + newStones + " stones left");
            }
            // Computer Turn
            int cm = 1;
            while (cm == 1) {
                comp = validEntry2(comp);
                if ( (newStones - comp) < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
                } else {
                    cm = 2;
                    newStones -= comp;
                }
                // Does Computer Lose?
                if (newStones == 0) {
                    System.out.println("You just beat the computer!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("There are " + newStones + " stones left");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you wrote this code you should be able to solve this. Learning how to debug a program can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no {} for your first if's else clause, thereby always executing cm=2 and immediately breaking the while loop.

Since that part of the code is indented, I highly suspect that is not your intention?

---

Edit: Your main function has a while loop that runs as long as `pl` is set to 1. As soon as `pl` is set to 2 the loop exits and therefore terminates your program. So you might wanna think about the exit condition of this loop.

In general there are a couple of things that I would improve to make debugging your code easier. For example, instead of having the two while-loops in your main function nested, execute them after each other (ideally in separate functions, so your code becomes a bit tidier). Then you can have a loop over both turns until there are no more stones left.

Comment: I fixed any {} issues in the code, however it still only loops it the first time. :/